# Onclick not working on Knockout array binded fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Im working on a CRUD Table populated using Knockout. jQuery Click event is not working on new pushed elements to the observable array

**click event function**

```
$('td').on('click', function () {
    var spanElement = $(this).find('span');
    $(this).find('span').hide();
    $(this).find('input').show().select().on('blur', function () {
        $(this).hide();
        spanElement.show();
    });
});
```

This code is working for all rows populated on-load, but not for those I add using add button.

Why is it so? How to fix it?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sreekeshokky/vzTh8/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you are adding the event handler directly to the table cells. When you add new rows, you never add the click element.

To solve this problem, apply the click event to the table and let event delegation take over

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var spanElement = $(this).find('span').hide();
    $(this).find('input').show().select().on('blur', function () {
        $(this).hide();
        spanElement.show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'table td', function () {

//Your Functions

});
```